# Python: Clicking through all possible (changing) menu combinations

Tags: python, recursion

I have 3 menus, where each menu depends on the subsequent menu choice (`menu_3` depends on `menu_2` selection, `menu_2` depends on `menu_1` selection). I'm trying to get every possible combination by clicking through to the last menu, then iterating through the options. Then going back to `menu_2`, select the next item, and iterate through all of the NEW `menu_3` options. I keep creating either an endless loop/infinite recursion, or I get through one iteration and it stops.

(I'm doing this on a website, so instead of continuing to send requests to the site, I'm trying to work through it locally.)

Here's where I am currently, which is creating an infinite recursion:

```
menu_1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
menu_2 = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'fish']
menu_3 = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']
menu_names = ['menu 1', 'menu 2', 'menu 3']
menus = [menu_1, menu_2, menu_3]

def recursion_testing(depth = len(menus) - 1, count = 0):
    for i in range(depth):
        print('count: ' + str(count))
        if count == depth:
            print('menu: ' + menu_names[count])
            for j in range(len(menus[count])):
                print(menus[count][j])
            count = 0
        else:
            return recursion_testing(depth, count+1)

recursion_testing()
```

Ultimately, my output would be the lists that show up when you click on `red`, `orange`, etc. If I can get this little test to output something like this, I could figure out the last bit:

```
'apple'
'cat'
'red'
'orange'
'yellow'
'green'
'blue'
'apple'
'dog
'red'
'orange'
'yellow'
'green'
'blue'
```

...etc.

Comment: remove the for loop..

Comment: I recommend using while loops for recursions, ideal for recursive functions, can you clarify more what your expecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a simple recursion:

```
menu_1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
menu_2 = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'fish']
menu_3 = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']
menu_names = ['menu 1', 'menu 2', 'menu 3']
menus = [menu_1, menu_2, menu_3]


def recursion_testing(menus):
    """Returns a list of solutions
    each solution is a list of strings"""
    if len(menus) == 1:
        return [menus[0]]

    subtree_solutions = recursion_testing(menus[1:])
    return [[item] + subtree_solution for item in menus[0] for subtree_solution in subtree_solutions]

print(recursion_testing(menus))
# [['apple', 'cat', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['apple', 'dog', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['apple', 'bird', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['apple', 'fish', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['orange', 'cat', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['orange', 'dog', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['orange', 'bird', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['orange', 'fish', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['banana', 'cat', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['banana', 'dog', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['banana', 'bird', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], ['banana', 'fish', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']]


# or if you want a flat list
import itertools
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(recursion_testing(menus))))
# ['apple', 'cat', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'apple', 'dog', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'apple', 'bird', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'apple', 'fish', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'cat', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'dog', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'bird', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'fish', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'banana', 'cat', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'banana', 'dog', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'banana', 'bird', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'banana', 'fish', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']
```

If the depth of menus is always the same, just make nested `for` loops (see one of the other answers)

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the list, now just need to extrapolate to the actual menus. I also got it working using nested dictionaries, but I was trying to get more comfortable with recursion. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

By experience, i think you should be using a dictionary to store your menus. This way you can count the tree leafs more easily (and count tree branches, which are here menu combinations).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion to get all possibilities of these menus, since they are finite in number:

```
allOptions = []
for mi1 in menu_1:
    for mi2 in menu_2:
        for mi3 in menu_3:
            allOptions.append( (mi1, mi2, mi3) )
```

This gives you all possible length-3 combinations of your menus.